# Stick events to top even if length is lower

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar to do a Vacation's map. And so far is working fine but I wanted to make a tweak on the information displayed.
[image]

I want the red/pinkish events to appear above all orange ones. As you can see the eventOrder works fine on the 12th because they have the same length. My problem is with what you can see on the 5th. Since the orange event has a higher length than the others eventOrder is not working.

Is there a property on the fullCalendar that I'm not seeing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the event JSON data please? Otherwise it's unclear what might need to be altered, or if it's even possible. Generally the events are shown in date order, as you might reasonably expect of a calendar.

Comment: I don't think the JSON would help. If this is to be solved is by using a property of fullCalendar or a callback.

Comment: why not? We need to understand the structure of your data, otherwise we don't know if it's simply something that could be solved by altering that. You say "as you can see the eventOrder works fine on the 12th". But I can't verify that because I don't know what the underlying data was, so i can't say if it worked ok or not.